# Why does element[class=noquotes] work?

Tags: html, css, w3c

As per MDN attribute selector in css has the following syntax:

```
div[attr="actualValue"]
```

Or like this example:

```
<div class="test"></div>  

div[class="test"]
```

But I noticed that the quotes around the `test` are not needed as:

```
div[class=test]
```

Example:

```css
div[class=test] {
  background: #6ea7b2;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">I am a div</div>
```

Why is this? Does w3c spec allow attribute selection without quotes around the value?

Answer (score 2):

[From the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation):

> Attribute values must be CSS [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) or [strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings).

`"test"` is a string, which is fine.

`test` is an identifier, which is fine.

Comment: As to why? I presume it's for parity with HTML, which allows the same. (Bet half the people reading this didn't know that either.)